# Can I bound my solution to Project Euler # 37?

Tags: primes

I'm working my way through the Euler project and have come to this one:

> The number 3797 has an interesting property. Being prime itself, it is
>   possible to continuously remove digits from left to right, and remain
>   prime at each stage: 3797, 797, 97, and 7. Similarly we can work from
>   right to left: 3797, 379, 37, and 3.
>
> Find the sum of the only eleven primes that are both truncatable from
>   left to right and right to left.
>
> NOTE: 2, 3, 5, and 7 are not considered to be truncatable primes.

The solution, given that there are only 11 of these primes, is straightforward enough (although I'm sure you can be as clever as you want about optimization) and I won't give away the answer.

But how do we know there are only 11? That's just given, with no explanation. I haven't found a proof of this after a fair amount of searching, so does anyone know why we can make this assumption?

Comment: Is there an upper boundary?

Comment: That's essentially my question. How do we go about finding one? I don't see any properties of these numbers that would lend themselves to a natural boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this paper](http://www.ams.org/mcom/1977-31-137/S0025-5718-1977-0427213-2/S0025-5718-1977-0427213-2.pdf) By I. 0. Angelí and H. J. Godwin, they have found that . . .

- the largest left truncatable prime is 357686312646216567629137 (base 10)
- the largest right truncatable prime is 73939133 (base 10)

Using this information, you can examine all numbers between 0-73939133 and find the numbers that are both right and left truncatable.

Comment: This is great. Thank you.